# How to reset EditText after an action has been completed?

Tags: android, reset, android-edittext, revert

I would like to reset my EditText back to an empty "space" or a "hint" after a button has pressed that would have completed an activity with input from the EditText field.

My adventure with android thus beckons.

Cheers. Thank you !!

```
 //************-------------------SEND SMS----------------*********//
    btnSendSMS = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sms);
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sendSMS(dispEd.getText().toString(),msgEd.getText().toString());
        }

        private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, msg, null, null);
        }
    });
}

<EditText 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/edit"/>

<EditText 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/msg"/>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you should try

```
editText.setText("");
```

Update: Try setting text as `null`

```
editText.setText(null);
```

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
EditText edit;
edit.setText(null);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `ediText.getText().clear();`

It works like a charm for me.

Comment: absolutely! fantastic

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you're really looking for is setting 
`android:hint="text"` on your edittext in the layout XML.

No extra code is required to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If u want clear the EditText use-

```
name.setText("");
```

or

```
name.setText(null);
```

If u wanna add Hint

```
name.setText(null);
name.setHint("Enter First Team Name");
```

Else if you have already added hint earlier than just use this and hint will be displayed-

```
name.setText(null);
```